# How to make SQL Server 2008 Check Constraint of a table Allow Only Certain characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to create a check constraint for a table in SQL 2008 which would allow A-Z characters (non case sensitive), numbers, hyphen (-), dot(.), space and underscore (_).
Below is my current expression:
([company_code] not like '%[^A-Za-z0-9_ .+]%').

It fulfills all the above requirements except for hyphen. How could I make the expression allowing hyphen as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [ESCAPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) clause:

```
not like  '%[^A-Za-z0-9_ .+\-]%' escape '\'
```

The character after the escape character will be matched literally.