# How to Setup a Constraint to Restrict Char Field to a Set of Values?

Tags: sql-server, custom-fields, type-constraints

I am having a brain fart today.  In SQL Server (currently using 2008), how do I setup a char field to only accept a specific series of chars (roughly eight case sensitive letters)?  And I need to re-use this "custom field" in several tables.

I know I could setup another table and put a foreign key constraint on it. Is that the only way?

Comment: We'd need a bit (ok, a lot) more detail on the nature of the constraint you're trying to define. Only A-Z? Case sensitive? Embedded spaces? Specific series of chars?

Comment: @Philip Sorry.  I have just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the double negative construct, this only allows chars A to H

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK
   CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_MyColChars CHECK (
     MyColChars COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT LIKE '%[^ABCDEFGH]%'
     )
```

For re-use, use a udf

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckChars (@Value varchar(100))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN (CASE WHEN @Value NOT LIKE '%[^ABCDEFGH]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
END
GO

... CHECK (
      dbo.CheckChars (MyColChars) = 1
     )
```

If you wanted A_F, semi-colon and space it'd be `'%[^ABCDEF; ]%'` for example

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 for the 80s pic, mullet and all!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into creating a check constraint. This post has a matching pattern you could build off of:

[How to make SQL Server 2008 Check Constraint of a table Allow Only Certain characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298649/how-to-make-sql-server-2008-check-constraint-of-a-table-allow-only-certain-charac)

In order to get the case sensitive matching, remove 'a-z' in the pattern and create the check constraint with a case sensitive collation. This ensures case sensitive matching even if the server and database are case insensitive.